# Reading file contents from many processes at the same time

Tags: c#

I have a class library that gets called from a windows service, the class library can be called many times at the same time.

I have an issue where i have to read file contents in my class, so i get the error that the file is being used by another process if the class is getting called by many processes.

This is how i read the file content:

```
  File.ReadAllBytes("path");
```

What is the best solution in this case ?

Thank you

Comment: use a `lock` mechanism

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` should actually work from many threads and many processes. Do you open the same file (for reading or writing) somewhere else in your code? Or in another process?

Comment: this file (that i read from) is generated once the class library runs the first time. after that i will read from that file and never write to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize the access to the whole file using standard thread synchronization approaches.

The simplest one is `Monitor` using `lock` statement:

```
public class A
{
    private static readonly object _sync = new object();

    public void DoStuff() 
    {
          // All threads trying to enter this critical section will
          // wait until the first to enter exits it
          lock(_sync)
          {
              byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\file.jpg");
          }
    }
}
```

### Note

Firstly, I was understanding OP was accessing the file from different processes, but when I double-checked the statement:

> I have a class library that gets called from a windows service, the
>   class library can be called many times at the same time.

...I realized OP is calling a method which reads all bytes from some file within the same Windows service instance.

Comment: This will not work because the lock is private per `process`. But he needs a system wide lock.

Comment: @CSharper I wasn't sure about this. My original answer was going to use `Mutex`, but since OP states the library is being used many times within the same Windows service...

Comment: If this is true, than you answer is correct with the lock.

Comment: @CSharper I believe it should be a threading issue rather than a multi-process thing. "A windows service" states the question...

Comment: ILSpy shows that `File.ReadAllBytes` already uses a `FileStream` with `FileShare.Read`.

Comment: @Stephan I didn't know that

Comment: @Stephan Are you sure? Can you paste the code somewhere? Are you sure you're not talking about `FileMode`?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: `using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.None, Path.GetFileName(path), false, false, checkHost))`

Comment: @Stephan I checked myself. I removed that part in my answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates to access a file by setting its share permissions. The first `using` block creates and writes file, second and third `using` blocks access and read the file.

```
var fileName = "test.txt";
using (var fsWrite = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");

    fsWrite.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    fsWrite.Flush();

    using (var fsRead_1 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        var bufRead_1 = new byte[fsRead_1.Length];
        fsRead_1.Read(bufRead_1, 0, bufRead_1.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("fsRead_1:" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufRead_1));

        using (var fsRead_2 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            var bufRead_2 = new byte[fsRead_2.Length];
            fsRead_2.Read(bufRead_2, 0, bufRead_2.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("fsRead_2:" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufRead_2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't your answer saying exactly what has provided mine?

Comment: There's a minor difference. My code above does not work with `FileShare.Read` but with `FileShare.ReadWrite`. I tried to implement the worst case (Read a file while it is written)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Mutex` for syncing among different processes. `File.ReadAllBytes` uses a `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare.Read` when reads the file, so normally you don't need to use any locks here. So you get this exception because the file is being *written* somewhere (or at least is locked for writing).

**Solution 1 - if you are the one who writes this file**

```
private static Mutex mutex;

public void WriteFile(string path)
{
    Mutex mutex = GetOrCreateMutex();
    try
    {
        mutex.WaitOne();
        // TODO: ... write file
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

public byte[] ReadFile(string path)
{
    // Note: If you just read the file, this lock is completely unnecessary
    // because ReadAllFile uses Read access. This just protects the file
    // being read and written at the same time
    Mutex mutex = GetOrCreateMutex();
    try
    {
        mutex.WaitOne();
        return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

private static Mutex GetOrCreateMutex()
{
    try
    {
        mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("MyMutex");
    }
    catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
    {
        mutex = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");
    }
}
```

**Remark:** A `ReadWriteLock` would be better here because you can read a file safely parallelly when it is not being written; however, there is no built-in inter-process read-write lock in .NET. [Here is an example](http://www.joecheng.com/blog/entries/Writinganinter-processRea.html) how you can implement one with `Mutex` and `Semaphor` types.

**Solution 2 - if you just read the file**

You must simply being prepared that the file can be locked when it is being written by a 3rd process:

```
public byte[] TryReadFile(string path, int maxTry)
{
    Exception e;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxTry; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            e = io;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    throw e; // or just return null
}
```